# Custom QODBC query in QuickBooks for Excel extraction

Tags: sql, excel, quickbooks, qodbc, vba

I am using QODBC to extract QB data into Excel.  I would like to have a report that summarizes sales by customer. The query below is perfect until I started using jobs which are linked to the customer.  Now... the data lists jobs as separate lines to customers rather than rolling the jobs up to customers.  I would like to group all sales data by customer if possible.

```
sp_report CustomSummary show Label, Amount parameters DateFrom = {d'2017-01-01'}, DateTo={d'2017-12-31'}, AccountFilterType= 'OrdinaryIncome', SummarizeRowsBy = 'Customer', SummarizeColumnsBy = 'Month'
where RowType='DataRow'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below listed stored procedure.

```
sp_report CustomSummary show Label, Amount parameters DateFrom = {d'2021-01-01'}, DateTo={d'2021-12-31'}, AccountFilterType= 'OrdinaryIncome', SummarizeRowsBy = 'Customer', SummarizeColumnsBy = 'Month' where RowType='SubtotalRow'
```

When using `RowType='SubtotalRow'`, you should get a total of all the jobs for each of the customer.