# SSIS ADO.NET Source - SQL Command Query Error

Tags: ssis, ado.net, quickbooks, qodbc

I have a problem where I try to read some data from QuickBooks Desktop file in SSIS through ADO.NET Source using QODBC driver. Driver is set up correctly, because I am able to preview table contents of the file like so [image]

I am also successful in using SQL Command access mode when I do a simple query like `SELECT * FROM Item`.

But the moment I try to use SQL Command to incorporate a `WHERE` clause against `TimeModified` field like so: 
 `SELECT * FROM Item WHERE TimeModified >= '12/21/2022 1:16:34 PM'` 
 and try to preview I get an error saying this:
[image] 
Now, I sent that row by using table access mode into a derived column and looked up what type `TimeModified` column uses and saw that it uses `DBTIMESTAMP`. So I suspected that you can't use the `>=` operator on that type, so what I also tried in my query is utilizing the `DATE()` function on the `WHERE` clause, omitting the time piece like so (Although ideally I would like to keep the hours to be able to use them in my query as time is important but for test sake):
[image]
But as you can see I got the `Expected Lexical Element Not Found` error.

I originally intended for this to work through an expression in which I obtain a value for a variable of most recent date by querying from a database prior this step and then get the items from the `Item` table that are older than said date. However, now I completely cut the expression idea just for the sake of trying to get this to work but it doesn't seem like it wants to. Am I doing something wrong? I made some querying in SQL against a date field by using strings of various formats like I showed earlier and those queries in SQL Server all succeeded but here nothing works.

If you are interested how the connection to QuickBooks Desktop is made I am using 32bit QODBC Driver which you can see there as 'QuickBooks Data' in the ADO.NET Source.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Something to try. Cast on the right side of your where filter as a date. E.g., CAST('12/21/2022 1:15:34 PM' as DATETIME). Also, cast your TimeModified as a DATETIME so they are identical data types.

Comment: @tonyd I tried ```SELECT * FROM Item WHERE CAST(TimeModified AS datetime) >= CAST('12/21/2022 1:15:34 PM' AS datetime)``` and it gives me this error:
------------------
There was an error displaying the preview
ERROR [42000] [QODBC] [sql syntax error] Expected lexical element not found: = =, <>, <, <=, >, or >= (fqqb32.dll)

Comment: Looks like you may need to use the built-in QODBC proc SP_REPORTS. Not sure if SSIS will handle this correctly or not. 

See if these links are helpful: 
https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2369/0/how-to-use-the-quickbooks-reporting-engine-with-qodbc

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865455/custom-qodbc-query-in-quickbooks-for-excel-extraction

Comment: @tonyd I experimented with using ```sp_report``` in my SQL Command and that does work. The thing is that I am pretty sure it just shows you actual reports of things and not exactly the table of contents if you will. The overall issue is, I can do standart SQL queries fine. And if I query ```SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ListId = 'aaa'``` it works fine executing and bringing me back 0 records. Its just the converstion from TimeModified column that I am struggling with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. Apparently with QODBC when it comes to timestamps you have to query them by doing something like this: 
`SELECT * FROM Item WHERE TimeModified >= {ts '2022-12-16 15:05:55.000'} ORDER BY TimeModified DESC` 
Here is some more info: https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2407/0/qodbc-desktop-troubleshooting-problems-with-date-format